# find variant id based on attributes selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a following product object where it has variants and variants are dependent with attributes. For example, Product A has variants of

1. size M with color Black, Grey
2. Size L with color Black

To show it in object format this is how it looks

```js
{
  "variants": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Variant name 1",
      "price": null,
      "stock": 2,
      "variantAttributes": [{
          "attribute": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Size"
          },
          "values": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Medium",
            "value": "M"
          }]
        },
        {
          "attribute": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Color"
          },
          "values": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Black",
            "value": "#000"
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Variant name 2",
      "price": null,
      "stock": 2,
      "variantAttributes": [{
          "attribute": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Size"
          },
          "values": [{
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Large",
            "value": "L"
          }]
        },
        {
          "attribute": {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Color"
          },
          "values": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Black",
            "value": "#000"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the problem is I could not find the variant id the user has selected. For e.g if user selects product of size 'M' and of color 'Black' then the variant id should be '1' as per the example I have shared in object.

This is the UI

[image]

To show the attributes this is how I have done

```
function productVariantAttributesPicker(productVariantsAttributes, setSizeGuideOpen, handleColorChange,handleSizeChange,rest) {
  return Object.keys(productVariantsAttributes).map(
    (productVariantsAttributeId,i) => {
      const productVariantsAttribute =
        productVariantsAttributes[productVariantsAttributeId];
      const { slug, id } = productVariantsAttribute.attribute;
      if (slug === "color") {
        return <ColorPicker key={i} colorVariant={productVariantsAttributes[id]} handleColorChange={handleColorChange} selectedColor={rest.selectedColor}/>;
      }
      if (slug === "size") {
        return (
          <SizePicker
            key={i}
            sizeVariant={productVariantsAttributes[id]}
            // setDisplaySizesOpen={rest.setDisplaySizesOpen}
            setSizeGuideOpen={setSizeGuideOpen}
            handleSizeChange={handleSizeChange}
            selectedSize={rest.selectedSize}
          />
        );
      }
    }
  );
}

<div>
  {productVariantAttributesPicker(
    variants,
    setSizeGuideOpen,
    handleColorChange,
    handleSizeChange,
    {selectedSize,selectedColor}
  )}
  {selectedColor && selectedSize && (
    <div>
      <AddToCart handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart}></AddToCart>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to find variant id based on attributes selected by user where the selected atrributes is in such form?

```
const selected_size = {id: "1", name: "Medium", value: "M"}
const selected_color = {id: "3", name: "Black", value: "#000""}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to find a variant which its `variantAttributes` contains both `selected_size` and `selected_color`.

If so, the logic should is something like:

```js
function hasAttr(variantAttribute, id, value) {
  return variantAttribute.find(
    variant => {
      return variant.values.some((attrValue) => (attrValue.id === id && attrValue.value === value))
    }
  );
}
const variant = variants.find(
  (variant) => {
    return hasAttr(variant.variantAttributes, selected_size.id, selected_size.value) &&
      hasAttr(variant.variantAttributes, selected_color.id, selected_color.value);
  }
);
```

There is more generic way but I simplified the example to be more clear.

**Demo**

```js
const variants = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Variant name 1',
    price: null,
    stock: 2,
    variantAttributes: [{
        attribute: {
          id: '2',
          name: 'Size',
        },
        values: [{
          id: '1',
          name: 'Medium',
          value: 'M',
        }, ],
      },
      {
        attribute: {
          id: '3',
          name: 'Color',
        },
        values: [{
          id: '3',
          name: 'Black',
          value: '#000',
        }, ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Variant name 2',
    price: null,
    stock: 2,
    variantAttributes: [{
        attribute: {
          id: '2',
          name: 'Size',
        },
        values: [{
          id: '2',
          name: 'Large',
          value: 'L',
        }, ],
      },
      {
        attribute: {
          id: '3',
          name: 'Color',
        },
        values: [{
          id: '3',
          name: 'Black',
          value: '#000',
        }, ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const selected_size = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Medium',
  value: 'M'
};
const selected_color = {
  id: '3',
  name: 'Black',
  value: '#000'
};

function hasAttr(variantAttribute, id, value) {
  return variantAttribute.find(
    variant => {
      return variant.values.some((attrValue) => (attrValue.id === id && attrValue.value === value))
    }
  );
}
const variant = variants.find(
  (variant) => {
    return hasAttr(variant.variantAttributes, selected_size.id, selected_size.value) &&
      hasAttr(variant.variantAttributes, selected_color.id, selected_color.value);
  }
);

console.log(variant);
```